When the two rings are isomorphic.
Recently, I am reading books about ring and field theory. I have some questions.
Let $k$ be a field of $\operatorname{char}(k)=0$. Let $a, b\in k^{*}$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Moreover, we assume $k$ contains all $n$-th root of unities.
I wonder whether the following is true: $k(\sqrt[n]{a})=k(\sqrt[n]{b})$ if and only if
$k[x]/(x^{n}-a)\cong k[x]/(x^{n}-b)$ as $k$-algebras.
This is true when $x^{n}-a$ is an irreducible polynomial over $k$ since in this case we have $k(\sqrt[n]{a})\cong k[x]/(x^{n}-a)$.
However, how about $x^{n}-a$ is a reducible polynomial? In this case, whether it is ture?

Yes. The polynomial $x^n - a$ is the product of the minimal polynomials of certain roots $c_1,\dotsc,c_d$, each one having the form $\zeta^i \sqrt[n]{a}$. So the chinese remainder theorem implies $k[x]/(x^n-a) \cong k(c_1) \times \dots \times k(c_d) = k(\sqrt[n]{a})^d$. From here it's easy.
